# How do I recall code in java without rewriting it?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, println

Say I have allot of code like..

```
    "
    System.out.println("This is code");
    System.out.println("This is code");
    System.out.println("This is code");
    System.out.println("This is code");
    "
```

This same code keeps coming up in my program can I shorten it all into one line I can just use to call it in the future??

Comment: Look into _methods_.

Comment: .... and loops. Shoot, just read the first 2 chapters of pretty much any Java text. In fact this question suggests that you are suffering from the dreaded "Java textbook deficiency syndrome". This unfortunately isn't treatable on StackOverflow or other similar sites but luckily responds well to buying and reading a Java book.

Comment: .... .... and concatination of strings :) just wanted to add something..

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a for loop for that, and a method while you're at it:

```
public void doStuff()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        System.out.println("This is code");
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be `doStuff()`. It's up to you, of course, but I'd recommend following at least the [basic naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printStuff()
{
   print things inside a loop
}
```